# integer division or modulo by zero

Tags: python, division

```
def gcdIter(a, b):

'''
a, b: positive integers

returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.
'''

test = 0
if a > b:
    b = test
else:
    a = test
while test != 1:
    if a%test == 0 and b%test == 0:
        return test
    test -= 1
return 1
```

Why it would come out an error as I want to find the greatest common divisor of a & b?

Comment: What error does it give? It looks like you haven't indented the code inside your function, in which case the code is not in the function. The function is empty and will raise an SyntaxError.

Comment: `test = 0` - why error wouldn't come out?

Answer (score 0):

```
if a%test == 0 and b%test == 0:
```

This line errors, right?

```
test = 0
```

You can't do `% 0` because that doesn't work. You want to do `test = a` and `test = b` rather than the other way around. Also, you could just do `test = min(a, b)`. Also, use the Euclidean algorithm.

You don't need the `test = 0` because `if` doesn't have a scope, but again, just take out the `if` and do `test = min(a, b)`.